# Explanation of how ${test##*.} and ${test%%.*} works?

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a good way to explain how the below works?

```
~$ echo $test
en.to.tre
~$ echo ${test}
en.to.tre
~$ echo ${test%.*}
en.to
~$ echo ${test%%.*}
en
~$ echo ${test#*.}
to.tre
~$ echo ${test##*.}
tre
```

In particular I don't understand why `.` and `*` have to be swapped when removing/keeping from left/right.

Comment: You can check this: [wooledge.org - How can I use parameter expansion? How can I get substrings? How can I get a file without its extension, or get just a file's extension?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)

Comment: Maybe also check this: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22664

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` means "substring *starting* with `.`"; `*.` means "substring *ending* with `.`".
In the third and the fourth line, you remove the shortest/longest substring *starting* with `.` from the end; in the fifth and sixth line, you remove the shortest/longest substring *ending* with `.` from the beginning.

The strings after `#`, `%`, etc., are interpreted as globbing patterns (like filenames), not as regular expressions, so `.` stands for itself.